# ASP.NET Core Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS problem

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, https

I need some help. How can I to stop my ASP.NET Core application from redirecting to HTTPS?

Currently, when I enter e.g.,

```
http://www.homeautomationinternal.xyz/
```

It redirects to

```
https://www.homeautomationinternal.xyz/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several possibilities why your ASP.NET Core application redirects your requests from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. The two most common root causes are the following registration calls:

- `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`
- `app.UseHttps()`

The former enforces temporary redirection, while the latter one indicates permanent. These calls are generated into your `Startup` in most cases by default. But there are project types where you can define whether or not to **Configure for HTTPS**. (Visual Studio provides this opt-out functionality). For further information please check the following [MSDN security article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Other middlewares like **Url rewrite** can also cause redirection, but this has to be explicitly registered. It is not added by default to your `Startup`'s `Configure` method. Even reverse proxies (like *IIS*) can do that on your behalf.